# How does Windows Store purchase work?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase, windows-store

I'm having questions about how does exactly windows apps do the purchase. Let me clarify my question.
In UWP coding we use these codes to check if the product is purchased or not:

```
   var License = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation; 
   var Listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
```

And the question is that, how does this method understands that if we purchased it or not? It does do an HTTP Request every time?(I need details) Or loads from a file (Again I need details, What file, where)? I used to deal with Listing Simulator and It was an XML file. I think that store saves an XML file in a place that I don't know.

It's a real question for me to understand that how it works. I found nothing in Microsoft documents.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really *read* the Microsoft documentation.

It says right in the docs for [LoadListingInformationAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp#Windows_ApplicationModel_Store_CurrentApp_LoadListingInformationAsync_) method:

> "Calling this method requires an internet connection."

From that remark it's easy to infer that it is making an HTTP request **everytime**

The [LicenseInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp#Windows_ApplicationModel_Store_CurrentApp_LicenseInformation_) property however **does not** need an internet connection.

Comment: Read, but not carefully. so that LicenseInformation loads the data from Where?

Answer (score 0):

The `LoadListingInformationAsync` method lists all of the app meta data specific to the current market for the user. So all the product available should be provided no matter it's purchased or not.

The service works by sending requests to the Store server for the information you want. If you want to know more details, you can use fiddler to monitor the whole process when calling the method.

The `LicenseInformation` property loads the data from local storage. But currently there's no such documentation clarifying specific storage details.

Comment: I need details about storage part. :)